# Replace some data form a dataframe to another under specific conditions with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I everyone, I'm quite new to Pandas dataset but, so I won't attach code if not pseudo-code cause I have no idea how to implement this.

I have two DataFrames, one with a Job number and a date related (let's call this DF2) to it and the bigger one with a bunch of different data (this will be DF1).

I would like to compare DF1 with DF2 and if the string in DF1[jobNo.] is equal to a string in DF2[jobNo.] get DF1[Date] == DF2[Date].

Any ideas? I really need your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to check if the dates match when the jobNo match, my approach would be to merge the two dataframes on jobNo and compare the dates.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'jobNo': [0, 3, 1], 'date': [9, 8, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'jobNo': [0, 3, 2], 'date': [9, 5, 3]})

df3 = df2.merge(df1, on=["jobNo"], suffixes=('_2', '_1'))
df3["date_match"] = df3.apply(lambda x: x["date_2"] == x["date_1"], axis=1)
print(df3)


       jobNo  date_2  date_1  date_match
0      0       9       9        True
1      3       5       8       False
```

if what you mean by df1["date"]==df2["date"] is that we're going to change the date in df1 if there's a match then this code looks for a match and replaces the date using apply

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'jobNo': [0, 3, 1], 'date': [9, 8, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'jobNo': [0, 3, 2], 'date': [7, 5, 4]})

df1['new_date'] = df1.apply(lambda x: (x['date'] if x['jobNo']
                            not in df2['jobNo'
                            ].values else df2[df2['jobNo'] == x['jobNo'
                            ]]['date'].values[0]), axis=1)

print(df1)


   jobNo  date  new_date
0      0     9         7
1      3     8         5
2      1     3         3
```

Comment: Yeah, my idea was to check for each row of df1 in column = jobNo, if it matches in one of the lines of df2 jobNo if a match is found I would like to replace the date in df1 in the one found in df2.

Comment: Yeah so if you change df1["new_date"] to df1["date"] that should do the job